# How can I read from and write to HDFS remotely using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hadoop, hdfs, read-write

The HDFS is sitting on a remote server (`hdfs_server`). I can do `ssh user@hdfs_server` and use `cat` and `put` to read and write, respectively, but I’ve been asked not to touch the HDFS (except to write a file to it remotely). I need to use the local machine to read from and write to the HDFS.

How can I achieve this with Python? I found this code that seemingly does this, but I am not able to run it on my local machine to read and write on the remote HDFS:

```
import requests
import json
import os
import kerberos
import sys

node = os.getenv("namenode").split(",")
print (node)

local_file_path = sys.argv[1]
remote_file_path = sys.argv[2]
read_or_write = sys.argv[3]
print (local_file_path,remote_file_path)

def check_node_status(node):
        for name in node:
                print (name)
                request = requests.get("%s/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus"%name,
                                                           verify=False).json()
                status = request["beans"][0]["State"]
                print (name)
                print (status)
                if status =="active":
                        break
        return status,name

def kerberos_auth():
        __, krb_context = kerberos.authGSSClientInit("HTTP@hdfs_server")
        kerberos.authGSSClientStep(krb_context, "")
        negotiate_details = kerberos.authGSSClientResponse(krb_context)
        headers = {"Authorization": "Negotiate " + negotiate_details,
                    "Content-Type":"application/binary"}
        return headers

def kerberos_hdfs_upload(status,name,headers):
        if status =="active":
                data=open('%s'%local_file_path, 'rb').read()
                write_req = requests.put("%s/webhdfs/v1%s?op=CREATE&overwrite=true"%(name,remote_file_path),
                                         headers=headers,
                                         verify=False, 
                                         allow_redirects=True,
                                         data=data)
                print(write_req.text)

def kerberos_hdfs_read(status,name,headers):
        print(status)
        if status == "active":
                read = requests.get("%s/webhdfs/v1%s?op=OPEN"%(name,remote_file_path),
                                                        headers=headers,
                                    verify=False,
                                    allow_redirects=True)

                if read.status_code == 200:
                        data=open('%s'%local_file_path, 'wb')
                        data.write(read.content)
                        data.close()
                else : 
                        print(read.content)


status, name= check_node_status(node)
headers = kerberos_auth()
if read_or_write == "write":
        kerberos_hdfs_upload(status,name,headers)
elif read_or_write == "read":
        print("fun")
        kerberos_hdfs_read(status,name,headers)
```

When I run it on my local machine, it gives the error in line 7 (`node = os.getenv("namenode").split(",")`), obviously, because there is no `namenode` in my local system. So, how can I modify this code to read & write from the HDFS? Since this is literally my second day touching HDFS, I have absolutely no clue and am totally lost in how to make this work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** After doing `export namenode=hdfs_server`, the namenode error is gone. Upon running the script again, I get a new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_write_hdfs.py", line 9, in <module>
    local_file_path = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_write_hdfs.py", line 9, in <module>
    local_file_path = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So I tried running the script with 3 arguments (1 each to satisfy `sys.argv[1]`, `sys.argv[2]` and `sys.argv[3]`). I get the following error now:

```
$ python3 read_write_hdfs.py /home/embs/Desktop/hdfs_test/ /home/edhuser/testdata.txt read
['hdfs_server']
/home/embs/Desktop/hdfs_test/ /home/edhuser/testdata.txt
/home/embs/Desktop/hdfs_test/ /home/edhuser/testdata.txt
hdfs_server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_write_hdfs.py", line 64, in <module>
    status, name= check_node_status(node)
  File "read_write_hdfs.py", line 22, in check_node_status
    verify=False).json()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 67, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 570, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 644, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'hdfs_server/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_write_hdfs.py", line 66, in <module>
    status, name= check_node_status(node)
  File "read_write_hdfs.py", line 24, in check_node_status
    verify=False).json()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 67, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 570, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 644, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'hdfs_server/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus'
```

From the trace, because the error stems from the function `check_node_status(node)`, I think it is probably not able to connect to `hdfs_server`. How can I fix this please?

Comment: `Invalid schema`.... You're missing an `https://`

Comment: @cricket_007 I see. So, I put `kerberos.authGSSClientInit("HTTPS@hdfs_server")` instead of `kerberos.authGSSClientInit("HTTP@hdfs_server")` in the second function `kerberos_auth()`. But I still get the same error. Please advise.

Comment: Seen this library? https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos

Answer (score 0):

`os.getenv("namenode")` is looking for an environment variable `namenode`.

So export the env var and try running the script again.

```
export namenode=hdfs_server
```

I'm assuming hdfs_server isn't the actual server name. If is the actual command you typed then it's not the hostname it's an ssh alias. You'll need to check `~/.ssh/config` for the actual host name.

Comment: Yes, `hdfs_server` is not the actual server's name. I'll try what you suggested and post an update.

Comment: Yes, that error is now gone after exporting the env var. On running the script again, I get a new error. I have updated the question details to show that error. Please suggest.